# Using HAML elements inside a block of text

Tags: html, haml

I often want some html like this:

```
(<span id="items_shown">all</span> items shown)
```

which I end up getting by using haml like this:

```
%span><
  (
%span#items_shown><
  all
%span
  items shown)
```

Note that I end up having to create extra spans, and then having to control for the whitespace around those spans, in order to get the exact syntax that I want, without extra spaces between the first `(` and the `all`.

So here's the question. What's the best way of having the exact html above, to display `(all items shown)` with `all` in a span? Is there something more elegant than my haml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the FAQ to this effect](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation). The short answer is that Haml's not optimized for inline markup, and there's no shame in just using HTML if you need to.